# Recognize "010" and similar numbers as a palindrome using modulus in C++

Tags: c++, palindrome

First post! This is my second semester with "Advanced C & C++" so any help is GREATLY appreciated. I've already scoured as much of stackoverflow and a few other resources to try and help me understand what I'm doing (or not doing) with this slew of logically inept code.

The goal of this program is to recognize whether or not a 'number' given by the user is a palindrome. Sounds simple enough right?! Ugh...well this is what I have been stuck on:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <string>

using std::string;

#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{

//variable declarations
string buffer;

//user input
cout << "Enter a number to see if it is a palindrome[Q to quit]: ";
getline(cin, buffer);

//looooop
while(buffer != "Q" && buffer !="q")
{
  int userNum, length, sum = 0, temp;
  userNum = atoi(buffer.c_str());
  for(temp = userNum; userNum !=0; userNum=userNum/10)
  {
    length = userNum % 10;
    sum = sum*10+length;
  }
  if(temp==sum)
    cout << temp << " is a palindrome!!\n\n";
  else
    cout << buffer << " is NOT a palindrome!\n\n";

  cout << "Enter a number to see if it is a palindrome[Q to quit]: ";
  getline(cin, buffer);
}
}
```

The problem arises when input of "010", or "400" is given. "400" is essentially "00400" in this case and both should be seen as a palindrome.

Comment: Why would you not do it as a `string` or `char` array? It will be more generic that way, and it will work. As you pointed out, `00400` is equivalent to `400` and therefore you can _never_ be sure that it is/not a palindrome. If you want to be sure it's a number, then do a check, but keep a string representation and do the comparison using a loop across an integer half of the string (odd lengthed, middle characters are irrelevant), comparing the opposite character along the way.

Comment: `"010"` is not a number. It's a character sequence. And for this problem, that's a good thing. Numbers can't be palindromes, although their text representations can be.

Comment: The professor hasn't 'taught' us to use array's yet so the class has to find an alternative way to process this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to recognize a palindrome, you don't have to do `atoi`. Just pass from the start to the middle checking if

```
buffer[i] == buffer[length - i]
```

Second, use the `atoi` to make sure it is a number and you're done.

Other way is to compare the string with itself reversed:

```
string input;

cout << "Please enter a string: ";
cin >> input;

if (input == string(input.rbegin(), input.rend())) {
    cout << input << " is a palindrome";
}
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but does not address the "as a number" need in the last sentence of his question.

Comment: You don't need to construct a second string for this. [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) `(input.begin(), input.end(), input.rbegin(), input.rend())` will return a `std::pair` that contains the iterators where a mismatch happened. If they're `input.end()` and `input.rend()`, the string is a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to get trailing zeros for the given number as below:

```
int noOfTrailingZeros = str.length;
while(str[--noOfTrailingZeros]=='0');
noOfTrailingZeros = str.length - noOfTrailingZeros;
```

Or the integer way as:

```
int noOfTrailingZeros = str.length;
while(num%10==0)
{
    noOfTrailingZeros++;
    num/=10;
}
```

Now, check for the input string whether it has the same number of zeros befire the number or not as:

```
int counterZeros = 0;
while(str[counterZeros++]=='0');
```

check these 2 numbers and if trailing zeros are more than the zeros at beginning, add that many at the beginning and pass that string to palindrome function.

Comment: I might implement this tactic in addition to trying to separate each piece of the user's input. Still in the works, but I'm lovin the advice!